# My Mac keeps changing its DNS to 127.0.0.1

Tags: mac, dns

My Mac keeps changing its DNS to 127.0.0.1 and sometimes the internet just stops working (and I know 127.0.0.1 is localhost) and I have to change it back to 1.1.1.1. I have started a web server on my Mac before with Apache but I stopped it and I have messed with my hosts file before. Any clue why my Mac is doing this and does anyone know how to fix it?

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 11.2
BuildVersion:   20D64
```

```
$ scutil --dns
DNS configuration

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : cable.virginm.net
  nameserver[0] : 127.0.0.1
  flags    : Request A records, Request AAAA records
  reach    : 0x00030002 (Reachable,Local Address,Directly Reachable Address)

resolver #2
  domain   : local
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300000

resolver #3
  domain   : 254.169.in-addr.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300200

resolver #4
  domain   : 8.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300400

resolver #5
  domain   : 9.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300600

resolver #6
  domain   : a.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300800

resolver #7
  domain   : b.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 301000

DNS configuration (for scoped queries)

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : cable.virginm.net
  nameserver[0] : 127.0.0.1
  if_index : 6 (en0)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records, Request AAAA records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
```

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# macOS Notice
#
# This file is not consulted for DNS hostname resolution, address
# resolution, or the DNS query routing mechanism used by most
# processes on this system.
#
# To view the DNS configuration used by this system, use:
#   scutil --dns
#
# SEE ALSO
#   dns-sd(1), scutil(8)
#
# This file is automatically generated.
#
search cable.virginm.net
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: The hosts file will have no effect on the DNS issue. Have you noticed when it changes, what is happening at that point in time on your mac? Do you have any additional SW installed which might "mess up" the DNS? Like VPN, security SW, malware detection,....

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of `sw_vers`, `scutil --dns`, and `cat /etc/resolv.conf`. It would also be helpful to know what networking interfaces you have up and how they're configured. DNS servers can be manually configured, or they can come in via DHCP, PPP[oE], or VPN on any relavant interface, so you probably need to run some tests to eliminate the possibility this DNS setting is coming in from a misconfigured VPN service or DHCP server. Have you ever installed BIND or any other DNS server on this Mac?

Comment: Hi, kindly check if this similar thread can help you: [Why does my mac show 127.0.0.1 as the only DNS server?](https://superuser.com/questions/1508237/why-does-my-mac-show-127-0-0-1-as-the-only-dns-server)

Comment: @Zina I have a VPN (ProtonVPN and Bitdefender VPN) and an AV

Comment: @Spiff Not that I am aware of

Comment: @Zina I have added those outputs

Comment: I also have ProtonVPN and it always changes the DNS correctly - when turning on to their DNS server and back to mine when disconnecting. would you run the following: `lsof -nP -i4TCP:53 | grep LISTEN` <- this will list the process listening on port 53 (if any, but as it is redirected to localhost it might be a local process) and then search for the PID listed in the output `ps aux | grep <PID from previous command`

Comment: @Zina When I enter `lsof -nP -i4TCP:53 | grep LISTEN` It does not say anything

Comment: ok, that means that no process is listening on the port, so I would assume that you have some software which changes the DNS to 127.0.0.1 but does not listen on the port (like dnsmasq which listens on 127.0.0.1 for DNS requests). That (as Spiff) said, might be a misconfiguration of VPN or DHCP configs. Can you see the change after you perform some action or specific activity, or is it random like in the change appears even if you do not use your computer?

Comment: @Zina I think I have fixed the problem just needed to edit `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf` to say the dns I wanted

Comment: Well, per content in /etc/resolv.conf - on macOS it is autogenerated, so your changes could disappear again for example after connecting and then disconnecting from VPN

Comment: @Zina yeah that is a bit annoying

Comment: @Zina Fixed it turns out it was an app messing with my dns which i uninstalled

Comment: would you share what app? it might help other people.

Comment: @Zina Lokinet a app which let's you connect to Lokinet

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question was self-solved as shown in this comment “[Fixed it turns out it was an app messing with my dns which I uninstalled.](https://superuser.com/questions/1629766/my-mac-keeps-changing-its-dns-to-127-0-0-1#comment2494359_1629766)” and this comment, “[Lokinet a app which let's you connect to Lokinet](https://superuser.com/questions/1629766/my-mac-keeps-changing-its-dns-to-127-0-0-1#comment2494359_1629766).”

Answer (score 0):

If you are running AdGuard with DNS Protection enabled (using AdGuard DNS), the program forces 127.0.0.1 to be the default DNS server.

Disable DNS Protection, or set DNS Protection to be 'System Default', and DNS settings will go back to their default state.

Comment: This question was self-solved as shown in this comment “[Fixed it turns out it was an app messing with my dns which I uninstalled.](https://superuser.com/questions/1629766/my-mac-keeps-changing-its-dns-to-127-0-0-1#comment2494359_1629766)” and this comment, “[Lokinet a app which let's you connect to Lokinet](https://superuser.com/questions/1629766/my-mac-keeps-changing-its-dns-to-127-0-0-1#comment2494359_1629766).”

Comment: Same issue with Cloudflare WARP, 
Disable WARP and DNS server will no longer be  127.0.2.2 or  127.0.2.3